# How to analyze interdependent interaction terms of lmer model

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, interaction, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

Assume I test a number of patients repeatedly over time to see how a certain treatment changes their skin conductance in response to a certain colour (`cond`) after 2 months, 4 months, ... etc. I test the skin conductance on the palm, wrist or arm simultaneously to see whether the place matters.

I have a longitudinal dataset of the form:

`SC` = skin conductance: dependent variable (metric)
`time` = fixed factor with 6 levels (time1, time2, ..., time6) for each measurement in time
`place` = fixed factor with 3 levels (place A, place B, place C)
`cond` = fixed factor with 2 levels (cond1=blue, cond2=red)
`ID` = random factor with subject ID (because not each subject could be tested at each time point)

I put the data into the following form:

```
data$time  <- relevel(data$time, "time1")
data$cond  <- relevel(data$time, "blue")
data$place <- relevel(data$time, "placeA")
```

and do some model comparison:

```r
model_1  <- lmer(sc ~ time * cond * place + (1 | ID), data)
model_1x <- update(model_1, REML = F)

model_2  <- update(model_1, .~. - time:cond:place)
model_2x <- update(model_2, REML = F)
anova(model_2x, model_1x)
# three-way interaction is not significant (p=0.93) --> leave three-way 
#  interaction out and continue with model_2

# remove two-way interactions:
model_3  <- update(model_2, .~. - time:cond)
model_3x <- update(model_3, REML = F)
model_4  <- update(model_2, .~. - time:place)
model_4x <- update(model_4, REML = F)
model_5  <- update(model_2, .~. - cond:place)
model_5x <- update(model_5, REML = F)
anova(model_3x, model_2x) # interaction is significant (p=0.003)**
anova(model_4x, model_2x) # interaction is not significant (p=0.46)
anova(model_5x, model_2x) # interaction is significant (p=0.039) *
```

In the end I end up with the final model being 
`sc ~ time + cond + place + time:cond + cond:place + (1|ID), data)`

**Here are my questions:**

- How can I look into the interaction terms? If e.g. `place` would have been dropped from the model altogether, looking at the following post hoc test would take the average over the factor `place`, right?

  ```
  posthoc_test <- glht(model_final, c("condred == 0", "condred + time2:condred == 0", 
                    ..., "condred + time6:condred == 0"))
  ```

Because, however, the factor `place` is still in the model, the above post hoc test is applied only to the baseline level of `place`, i.e. `placeA`

What if I want to see how `time` and `cond` interact, regardless of `place`? Is this even possible given that `place` is itself "captured" in the interaction `cond:place`?

- How do I report the significant interactions? Is the p-value I get from the model selection procedure (i.e., p=0.003 for `time:cond`) also the one I can later report for `time:cond`?

P.S.
By now I'm almost convinced that the answer to question 2 is, that the values I get from the model comparison are the ones I can report for `time:cond` in general. In short: it doesn't matter that I got the values from a model comparison instead of getting them from a preformulated ANOVA.

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to look into the `time:cond` term I would check least-square (LS) means of `sc` at the 6 unique levels of `time` within each level of `cond`, and vice versa, using the final model. I would keep significant `place` and `cond:place` in calculating the LS means because removing these might give misleading values. This can be done using the `lsmeans` package:

```
lsmeans(model_final, ~ time|cond, cov.reduce = FALSE) ## or  ~ cond|time
```

Then I would repeat the same for the `cond:place` interaction.

Second, if you want to obtain "exact" p-values, I suggest you use `lmerTest` package. (The Kenward-Roger approximation it uses gives you exact degrees of freedom and hence p-values for the F-test if the data are balanced and have no no missing values.)

Comment: Thanks, Masato! This finally brought me on the right track. Now `summary(glht(model, lsm(pairwise ~time|cond)))` does what I want :-)