Can I use the function HSD.test as a post-hoc test for two-way ANOVA in R?
I've done two-way ANOVA with interaction (edit) and now I want to do a post-hoc test. I have 2 factors and both have just 2 categories. I've found the function HSD.test from agricolae package and I really like that it gives you the groups and letters regarding how the groups differ. But I'm not sure if this function can be used with two factors or if it works right only if you have one-way ANOVA. Does anybody know?
Edit: I did the ANOVA to test a hypothesis that neither of the 2 factors has an effect on the continuous dependent variable. I rejected the hypothesis and now I want to know how the 4 groups differ between themselves. How should I test this?

Welcome to the site. Can you share a bit more detail about your data? Also, if each factor really only has two categories then there’s no need for post hoc tests. To see why, consider the null and alternative hypotheses of ANOVA.

Actually it's a bit more complicated, in total I have about 10 blood parameters (continuous, e.g. concentration of Na) and 2 factors - season (start/end) and locality (A/B). I did two-way ANOVA with interaction for each parameter seperately with Holm correction. To present my results, I would like to do a boxplot for each parameter and I should somehow highlight between which boxes is a difference... So I liked that the HDS.test gives me the letters which I could write above the boxes. But now I realized I probably should do the Holm correction to the HSD test as well, but I don't know how.

Thanks. Please consider adding the info from your comment to your question as it provides important context. It now sounds like you want to compare the results of different significance tests, which is not what Tukey's HDS is for.

I'm sorry, I'm quite confused. Could you please elaborate? I'm sorry for my ignorance, but I'm new to this..

Ah, ok, I see what you mean, thanks for the edits. I still think you may have little more to do, but see this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115818/post-hoc-tests-for-2x2-anovas-type-ii-iii-with-interactions-in-r?rq=1

Thank you very much! I'm sorry for being unclear..
