# F stats for post hoc test of a linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model, post-hoc, f-statistic

I have an unbalanced linear mixed effects model with three fixed factors of various levels and one random factor for my repeated measures data ([for details see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99742/how-to-analyze-interdependent-interaction-terms-of-lmer-model)).
Thanks to your help I managed to do post-hoc tests on the significant interaction terms using `lsm` from the **lsmeans** package. However, I need to report the F statistic (F value and degrees of freedom) for these post-hoc tests and wonder how???

Here is what I do:

1. Model comparison using `anova()` resulting into the final model
   `model_final`, which reads:

   `sc ~ time + cond + place + time:cond + cond:place + (1|ID), data)` .
2. I analyze the significant interaction time:cond using `lsmeans`:

   `posthoc_1 <- glht(model_final, lsm(pairwise ~ cond|time)`

   `summary(posthoc_1)`

and get sth like below for each level of `time`, here is the example for `time1`.

```
> Note: df set to 268 
>
> $`time = time1`
> 
>    Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
> 
> Fit: lme4::lmer(formula = sc ~ time + cond + place + time:cond + cond:place + (1|ID), data)
> 
> Linear Hypotheses:
>                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
> cond1 - cond2 == 0   3.1867     0.6797   4.688 4.39e-06 ***
```

This gives me t-values for the various levels of the interaction terms and their corresponding p-value, but no F stats!

My questions:

1. Is there any way of obtaining the F stats? (F value and degree of
   freedom)
2. Or am I stuck with the t-values? If so, is t(0.095;268) =
   4.588, p < 0.001 reporting the correct degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `lsmeans` function directly rather than via `glht`, you might have better luck.

```
library(lsmeans)
( mod.pairs = contrast(lsmeans(model_final, ~ cond|time), "trt.vs.ctrl1") )
```

At this point, what you have is pairwise comparisons at each `time`. Is it the `cond:time` interaction you want to test? If so, compute contrasts of the above differences (column labeled `contrast`):

```
inter.con = contrast(mod.pairs, "trt.vs.ctrl1", by = NULL)
test(inter.con, joint = TRUE)
```

I'm suggesting using `trt.vs.ctrl1` contrasts because it makes the right number of contrasts to match the d.f. However if you use `pairwise` instead, it will give the same results (it will just have to work harder).

PS this does require the latest version of **lsmeans** (2.12) because the `joint` option was not avaialble before then.

Comment: Thanks, rvl, yes, it is the `cond:time` interaction I want to test to see at _which_ `time` the two levels of `cond` differ significantly. The first two lines of code give me the exact same output as the `lsm()` command within `glht`, so that's fine. I'm afraid, I don't understand what you are doing with the last bit of code (inter.con and then the test()-bit). Do I actually make contrasts of contrasts there? I do not want an overall F stat but an F stat for each `cond`-comparison of every level of `time`.

Comment: Yes. Interactions are quantified by taking contrasts of contrasts. If you want $F$ tests for individual contrasts, just compute $F=t^2$ with $(1,df)$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Ah, now I get it :-) The quantification of the interaction I actually already got with `anova(model_final)`. Squaring the t value is what I resigned to, too, but I thought there might be a more elegant way... Thanks anyway!